# Getting IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory error when trying to run PyInstaller

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable file for my Python script using PyInstaller. I run in the terminal...

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed ./lab_attendant_emailer.py

From the directory that the python file is in. It starts running for a bit but returns this error.

```
12 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1.1
12 INFO: Python: 2.7.6
12 INFO: Platform: Linux-3.16.0-67-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
12 INFO: wrote /home/carsnwd/PycharmProjects/labattendantemailer/lab_attendant_emailer.spec
14 INFO: UPX is not available.
15 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/carsnwd/PycharmProjects/labattendantemailer',
 '/home/carsnwd/PycharmProjects/labattendantemailer']
15 INFO: checking Analysis
21 INFO: checking PYZ
22 INFO: checking PKG
25 INFO: Bootloader /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
25 INFO: checking EXE
25 INFO: Building because name changed
25 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 755, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 701, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 498, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 183, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 575, in assemble
    outf = open(self.name, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/carsnwd/PycharmProjects/labattendantemailer/dist/lab_attendant_emailer'
```

Any help with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Carson, at first view, this looks like you might be gave same name for directory and executable file, so when It try to write it gives error, please changes name for executable

Comment: Remove directory `/home/carsnwd/PycharmProjects/labattendantemailer/dist` and run `pyinstaller` again.

Comment: Oh man, I thought I tried that once already, it worked this time though lol thank you!

Comment: Let me give you answer, please select it as answer so if someone else face problem, he get correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be run `pyinstaller` once and it creates `dist` directory.

When you try to rerun again, it has all directory structure created with previous command. Please cleanup your directory then rerun `pyinstaller`, that will work.